# Outlook data file cannot be accessed (error 8004010F)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I've rebuilt the user profile twice, we're using windows 7 still getting this message.  Any clues? 
Thanks!

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2659085

Comment: You rebuilt the profile, so the above link is not appropriate. Could be a lot of reasons. Here's one potential solution: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0acbed9c-de08-40f7-a77e-2cd0e626d9cb/outlook-data-file-cannot-be-accessed-error-8004010f?forum=outlook

Comment: Exactly when do you get the message? What the exact message it gives you? Have you got any 3rd party add-ons installed in Outlook?  If you run Outlook in safe mode(`outlook.exe /safe`) does it still do it?